# Variety - union of lines between a smooth point and a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I came in contact with this problem about projective variety:

Let X be an irreducible curve of degree d>1 in $P^3$. Let P be a
smooth point of X. Let Y be the closure of the set $$\bigcup_{Q\in X\setminus\{P\}}\bar{PQ}$$ where $\bar{PQ}$ denotes the projective line passing through P and Q.

(1) Show that Y is an irreducible variety.

(2) Show that dim(Y ) = 2.

(3) Show that deg(Y ) < d.

I solved the first two points partially but I am stucked on the third. For instance, for the first point I worked by contradiction:

Without loss of generality, suppose by contradiction that $ Y=\mathbb{V}(f)\cup\mathbb{V}(g) $ with $ f,\,g $ irreducible (indeed if $ f=f_1\cdot f_2, $, with $ f_j $ irreducible, then $ \mathbb{V}(f)=\mathbb{V}(f_1)\cup\mathbb{V}(f_2) $).
The degree of $ X $ is $ d $, so let's consider $ L $ a linear subvariety of codimension 1 through $ P $ and a $ Q\in X\setminus\{P\} $ such that $ \#(L\cap X)=d $, and call $ l $ the line through $ P $ and $ Q $.
Then, $ l\subset Y=\mathbb{V}(f)\cup\mathbb{V}(g),\,l\subset L $ and $ X\subset Y=\mathbb{V}(f)\cup\mathbb{V}(g) $.
Since $ f,\,g $ are irreducible, we have either $ X=\mathbb{V}(f) $ or $ X=\mathbb{V}(g) $ or $ X=\mathbb{V}(f)\cap\mathbb{V}(f) $. Suppose the first case is true. Then $ Y=X\cup\mathbb{V}(g) $. Hence,
$$ l=l\cap L\subset L\cap Y=L\cap(X\cup\mathbb{V}(g))=(L\cap X)\cup(L\cap\mathbb{V}(g)) $$
But, taking the cardinality  $$ \#l\leq\#(L\cap X)+\#(L\cap\mathbb{V}(g)). $$
Now, the first term is infinite and the first summand of the second term is equal to $ d<\infty $, thus we have $ \#(L\cap\mathbb{V}(g))=\infty $. This means that $ \mathbb{V}(g)\subset L $.
Thus, $ Y=X\cup\mathbb{V}(g)\subset X\cup L $. But, this is a contradiction. Indeed, since $ p $ is smooth, $ \dim T_pX=\dim X=1 $, i.e. $ T_pX $ is a line and it "touches" the curve just in $ p $. But, since $ p $ is smooth, $ T_pX $ lays in the closure of $ \bigcup_{Q\in X\setminus\{P\}}\overline{PQ} $, i.e. $ T_pX\subset Y $, but $ T_pX $ is not contained in $ L $, since $ Q\notin T_pX $. Hence, $ Y $ cannot be contained in $ X\cup L $.
So, $ Y $ is irreducible.

For the second point, instead:
$ Y $ is the closure of $$ \{[P_1-Q_1:P_2-Q_2:P_3-Q_3]\,|\,Q\in X\setminus\{P\}\} $$
which, on the open subset of $ \mathbb{P}^2 $ with $ P_3-Q_3\neq0 $, is $$ \{[\frac{P_1-Q_1}{P_3-Q_3}:\frac{P_2-Q_2}{P_3-Q_3}:1]\,|\,Q\in X,\,P_3\neq Q_3\} $$
and this set is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{A}^2 $, because the first 2 components are independent. Then, $ \dim(Y)=\dim(\mathbb{A}^2)=2 $.

Someone can give me any advice for the last point, please?

Comment: If $C_1:=Z(F) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2_k$ is a plane projective curve defined by a homogeneous polynomial $F(x,y,z)$ of degree $d$, it follows $deg(C_1)=d$ - the degree depends on the embedding $C_1 \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2_k$. Hence the degree $deg(Y)$ of your surface $Y$ depends on the ideal $I$ defining the embedding $Y\subseteq \mathbb{P}^3_k$.  How do you define this ideal $I$?

Comment: In fact you find some information on "degrees of secant varieties" in Section 10.4.2 in Harris/Eisenbud - "3264 and all that...". Your variety $Y$ seems to be a subvariety of the secant variety $Sec(2,X)$. In the reference you will a discussion of the secant variety of projective curves and the relation with symmetric products.

Comment: As an example: In the above reference they calculate the degree of the trisecant surface of a general rational curve of degree $d$. (Prop.10.19). Hence  the book may gives some ideas on how to approach your problem.

Comment: I will try to find something in there, thanks!

Comment: I believe you find a section where they use "contact bundles" and their Chern classes to calculate the degrees of secant varieties. Maybe this can be adapted to your situation.